# How to setState via Typeahead JS suggestion with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, typeahead.js, typeahead

I'm a ReactJS newbie and have built a basic app, with Typeahead JS integration. The functionality of Typeahead works great, however upon selecting the suggestion from Typeahead I want to setState in ReactJS, but I can't figure out how to do this (again, novice!).

Right now I can see the correct output in the console on selecting the Typeahead suggestion, I just cannot get this data anywhere in the app.

I've got a Codepen demo which explains further. Lines 94 onwards show where I have been trying to setState on Typeahead suggestion selection.

Thanks

[codepen demo app](http://codepen.io/stephenk/pen/gwaayB?editors=0011)

```
   .on('typeahead:selected', function (obj, datum) {

              console.log(datum.id);

              // SET ID to STATE HERE ========================/
              //   this.setState({
              //   movieID: datum.id,
              //   homepage: datum.homepage,
              //   original_title: datum.original_title
              // })
               // SET ID to STATE HERE ========================/


            }); // END Instantiate the Typeahead UI
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the callback function you've supplied to the `.on()` function to the React component.

```
.on('typeahead:selected', function (obj, datum) {
    this.setState({});
}.bind(this));
```